# Mojibake at the start of the command line when running a .bat

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

I am trying to create a `batch` file that could run my `python3` script. So far I got errors... I taken screenshots of information down below.

Let me illustrate:

[1: Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN5fv.png) - That is my c disk. There I have a script and .bat file

[2: Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4wUL.png) - Trying to launch script double clicking it works fine.

[3. .bat code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajb41.png) - This is my .bat file code, that i changed numerous times.

[4. .bat result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl41K.png) - yet it does not work...

[5. try to call python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGqq6.png) - if i try to call
[*Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw5Uf.png) - even tho i have its path mapped

[6. Copied pasted python dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6pFQ.png) - even tried to copy paste the main dir of the python, same error same problem.

Maybe there is a simple fix that I am missing here. Please share ideas bellow. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/601282/%cc%81-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: That said, 1)do not use root folder for work; 2) use the Py launcher, or add `python.exe` to `PATH`, or associate the `.py` extension with it (all are available as options during install) to invoke it easily.

Comment: And one more: DO NOT POST TEXT AS PICTURES.

Comment: Sir, yes sir! Thank you, I had path added during installation.

Comment: If `python.exe` is on the `PATH`, you can run just `python` without a full path. If it's associated with `.py`, you can just run `<optionally_path_to\>script.py`.

Comment: @py works fine thank you

Comment: In the future please copy and paste the text into your question instead of creating screen shots.  Makes it very difficult to view all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://superuser.com/questions/601282/%cc%81-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command , the reason is that Notepad adds a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when you save the text as Unicode.

Explicitly save the `.bat` as ANSI with `Save As...`.